# Does prefetching affect SEO even if there is a dynamic metadata when using Next JS 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm currently building an e-commerce app with Next JS 13.4. in my home page i display all the items fetched from firebase Firestore. and i've wrapped those items inside next Link. so whenever the user clicks on a specific item it navigates to a detail page with dynamic routing.

there is a feature in Next Link to not pre-fetch the detail pages before loading. if i make the pre-fetch false it stops and i save from making unnecessary get request which saves me a document read. but if i don't it prefetches and loads the pages. and this will make a get request to firebase (server) which will count as a read. even if it preloads whenever it routes to the detail page, it doesn't cache the data it calls for that doc again.

for the detail page i've created a dynamic metadata. so my question is that if i make the prefetch false does that affect SEO without prefetching even if i have created a dynamic metadata?

Answer (score 0):

In general, prefetching *can be* a way of improving SEO, but it isn't super necessary for search engines. For SEO, the most important elements are that GoogleBot can see and render the page.

You could implement a hybrid approach-- set prefetch to true, use Next.js's data fetching/caching capabilities to minimize redundant document reads, and dynamically set metadata. (Some info about that [here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-2#built-in-seo-support-with-new-metadata-api)) ([this video is worth a look too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1n7slbDB1bQ))

My major recommendation is to use the [rich results test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results): if your links and data show up, then Google can see them. If your site is generally speedy, then the difference between prefetching and not is not necessarily that important.